# Check for inconsistencies in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integrity

I have this data set with timestamps & station IDs and I'm trying to check for any inconsistencies  before performing my analysis. I was able to do that for the time stamp & durations with the below code (a). I'm trying to do the same to check if the start station ID is consistent with the station name & coordinates but I'm not sure how

By inconsistencies I mean if one station name show more than one ID or coordinates, the same applies for ID vs coordinates.

Also, here's the link to the data set
https://video.udacity-data.com/topher/2020/October/5f91cf38_201902-fordgobike-tripdata/201902-fordgobike-tripdata.csv

[image: Here's a picture showing the data frame info]

```
        duration_sec                start_time                  end_time  start_station_id                                start_station_name  ...  bike_id   user_type  member_birth_year member_gender  bike_share_for_all_trip
0              52185  2019-02-28 17:32:10.1450  2019-03-01 08:01:55.9750              21.0  Montgomery St BART Station (Market St at 2nd St)  ...     4902    Customer             1984.0          Male                       No
1              42521  2019-02-28 18:53:21.7890  2019-03-01 06:42:03.0560              23.0                     The Embarcadero at Steuart St  ...     2535    Customer                NaN           NaN                       No
2              61854  2019-02-28 12:13:13.2180  2019-03-01 05:24:08.1460              86.0                           Market St at Dolores St  ...     5905    Customer             1972.0          Male                       No
3              36490  2019-02-28 17:54:26.0100  2019-03-01 04:02:36.8420             375.0                           Grove St at Masonic Ave  ...     6638  Subscriber             1989.0         Other                       No
4               1585  2019-02-28 23:54:18.5490  2019-03-01 00:20:44.0740               7.0                               Frank H Ogawa Plaza  ...     4898  Subscriber             1974.0          Male                      Yes
...              ...                       ...                       ...               ...                                               ...  ...      ...         ...                ...           ...                      ...
183407           480  2019-02-01 00:04:49.7240  2019-02-01 00:12:50.0340              27.0                           Beale St at Harrison St  ...     4832  Subscriber             1996.0          Male                       No
183408           313  2019-02-01 00:05:34.7440  2019-02-01 00:10:48.5020              21.0  Montgomery St BART Station (Market St at 2nd St)  ...     4960  Subscriber             1984.0          Male                       No
183409           141  2019-02-01 00:06:05.5490  2019-02-01 00:08:27.2200             278.0                            The Alameda at Bush St  ...     3824  Subscriber             1990.0          Male                      Yes
183410           139  2019-02-01 00:05:34.3600  2019-02-01 00:07:54.2870             220.0                       San Pablo Ave at MLK Jr Way  ...     5095  Subscriber             1988.0          Male                       No
183411           271  2019-02-01 00:00:20.6360  2019-02-01 00:04:52.0580              24.0                             Spear St at Folsom St  ...     1057  Subscriber             1989.0          Male                       No
```

a-

```
#Convert Start & End Time to date time & Check integrity of duration
df.start_time = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time)
df.end_time = pd.to_datetime(df.end_time)
df['calc_duration'] = df['end_time']-df['start_time']
df['calc_duration'] =df['calc_duration']/np.timedelta64(1,'s')
df['dur_diff']=np.abs(df['duration_sec']-df['calc_duration'])
df=df[df.dur_diff <= 1]
df.info()
```

Comment: What do you mean with inconsistencies?

Comment: I mean that if a station ID has multiple names at the same time or a name that has more than 1 coordinate or an ID with more than one coordinate

Comment: Provide examples in data form not images. Give a clear definition for inconsistances.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to check that each `start_station_id` has only one `'start_station_latitude'`,`'start_station_longitude'`, and `'start_station_name'`. You can select these columns and drop any duplicate values.

```
start_stations = df[['start_station_id','start_station_latitude','start_station_longitude','start_station_name']].drop_duplicates().dropna(subset=['start_station_id'])
```

This is the result:

```
start_stations
            start_station_id  start_station_latitude  start_station_longitude                                start_station_name
    0                   21.0               37.789625              -122.400811  Montgomery St BART Station (Market St at 2nd St)
    1                   23.0               37.791464              -122.391034                     The Embarcadero at Steuart St
    2                   86.0               37.769305              -122.426826                           Market St at Dolores St
    3                  375.0               37.774836              -122.446546                           Grove St at Masonic Ave
    4                    7.0               37.804562              -122.271738                               Frank H Ogawa Plaza
    ...                  ...                     ...                      ...                                               ...
    27232              301.0               37.318450              -121.883172                              Willow St at Vine St
    28959              226.0               37.781123              -122.232991                    26th Ave at International Blvd
    29478              234.0               37.778058              -122.225400                        Farnam St at Fruitvale Ave
    88038              224.0               37.784855              -122.239305                    21st Ave at International Blvd
    156498              37.0               37.785000              -122.395936                               2nd St at Folsom St
```

Now we can check that there aren't any duplicated `start_station_id` values in the `start_stations` DataFrame:

```
>>> start_stations[start_stations.duplicated(subset='start_station_id')]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [start_station_id, start_station_latitude, start_station_longitude, start_station_name]
Index: []
```

Since an empty DataFrame is returned, there are no `start_station_id` values with more than one `'start_station_latitude'`,`'start_station_longitude'`, or `'start_station_name'`